# Change roads color in "google maps android api v2"

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

I would like to know if there is an equivalent to javascript api v3: [Styled Maps](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html)
Because i need to change the roads color, and would like to mask road labels.

Is it possible directly from the android v2 api?

I tried to use javascript v3 api to fix the precedent problem but my app needs tilt like [this](http://gmaps-samples-flash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/Map3DSimple.html) too and it looks like no tilt for javascript v3 api :( .

Finaly, do someone have a solution to:
add tilt to javascript v3 api for ROADMAP
or/and
change the roads color in android v2 api

Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you are not able to do either of these at this point. The JavaScript Maps API does not support tilting, the Android v2 API does not support styled maps.

Comment: Do you know how they do in 'ingress' app ?

Comment: Ingress doesn't use the Maps API

Comment: It uses a custom Google only implementation not available to the public.

Comment: :( maybe using polylines in android v2 and directions api (but i would need a way including all the visible roads) no ?

Comment: @ManoMarks any idea if this custom implementation will become public? or some version of it?

Comment: @Patrick, you can track the [feature request here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5463)